# glassfish connection pool additional delay while re-creating after idle timeout

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, glassfish, connection-pooling

We are currently deploying some applications on a `glassfish 3.0.1` using a `postgres database` through `postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar`
Our actual configuration regarding the connexion pool is:

Idle Timeout: 120 seconds
Max Wait Time: 60000 milliseconds
Initial and Minimum Pool Size: 1
Maximum Pool Size: 1
Pool Resize Quantity: 1

We have noticed that the database connexions are droped and created every `140 seconds` instead of `120 seconds`.

Is there something we have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably being active for 20 seconds.  Checking that the connection is valid etc.

Comment: We are carefully monitoring the network for activity, and we have absolutely no traffic, the server is started alone and nothing get through it and the database. Additionally, the database and the glassfish are not on the same machine.

Comment: Have you got a DBA which can analyse the connection at the DB end?  With Sybase we've found that things like having XA txns switched on can affect these timings

Comment: After some test with and without xa transactions I noticed as well a significant increase of the recycling delay. Without xa, the idle timeout work fine. with xa, 120 seconds became 180 and 240 seconds became 480. We are going to take care of this weird behavior. If someone know what make glassfish (or postgres JDBC) behave like that, please enlighten us. thanks.